# intel NUC8i3BEK with bad IR reception

Tags: infrared, intel-nuc

My new intel NUC8i3BEK has built-in infrared-sensor (called consumer infrared or CIR). 
The sensor works.
The remote-control is a Logitech Harmony One (which works perfectly with TV and former USB-IR-reciever).

But his reception-angle and reception-distance is really bad! The angle is less than 45 degrees horizontal and less than 45 degrees vertical.
My NUC is around 3m away from my couch, but the IR works good if distance is lower than 2m.

Can anyone confirm this issues?
Has anyone fixes for this?

Comment: Maybe some IR extenders might help?

Comment: @Anaksunaman : Thanx for your reply, but this isn't what I want. If there is an ir-reciever, than it should work. I do not want to install another device.